# Converting an array of integers into a single integer using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array with many integers.Now I want all these integers to be represented as a single integer.How to do it.

```
var a=["1","2","3"];
var a=123;  //To be displayed in this format as a whole number.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join),

```
var a=["1","2","3"];
a= a.join(""); //123
a= +a; //May be if you want to convert it as a number.
```

Note that the parameter for `join` is an empty string. There are 3 different ways to convert a string to a number. I have suggested one of the ways here. `parseInt(numberString, 10)` would be stable at times. For example, `+"12px"` will be `NaN` but `parseInt("12px", 10)` would be `12`

Comment: @Preethi Glad to help! :)

Comment: Can you help me with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436680/comparing-the-equality-of-two-variables-using-jquery?noredirect=1#comment60493186_36436680